# We have implemented proxy for Angular 8 application running on 4200 to back end api running on Tomcat 8080 is not working

Tags: angular, proxy

We have implemented proxy for Angular 8 application running on `:4200` to back end api running on `Tomcat 8080`. is not working

using angular version like below
    Angular CLI: 8.3.20
    Node: 12.13.1
    OS: win32 x64
    Angular: 8.2.14

```
    let me mention changes we did.
    proxy.conf.json 
    {
      "/student/allstudent": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "pathRewrite": {
          "^/student/allstudent": ""
        },
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
      }
    }

    in `package.json` we added this line "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
    In `angular.json` file we have added below proxy config under serve.
    "options": {
                "browserTarget": "PricingWorkBench-ui:build",
                "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
              },

    service method look like this in Angular 
    public getStudentDetails(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:8083/student/allstudent").
          pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
             return data;
            })
          )
      }
```

Still we are getting the below error please help me.

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8083/student/allstudent' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8083/student/allstudent", ok: false, …}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your endpoint is on `http://localhost:8083/student/allstudent`.

Your **proxy.conf.json** should be:

```
{
    "/student/allstudent": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8083",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And your method will look like:

```
public getStudentDetails(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("/student/allstudent").
        pipe(
            map((data: any) => {
                return data;
            })
        )
    }
}
```

Normally this route will evaluate to `http://localhost:4200/student/allstudent` but the proxy will take the route `/student/allstudent` and map it to the `target` listed in the `proxy.conf.json` which is `http://localhost:8083`

Comment: Thank you so much for you suggestion. actually i had 8083 only in my proxy i mentioned as 8080. But i tried chaning the get method as per you. now i can see my get url in browser as http://localhost:4200/student/allstudent. but it is not replacing with 8083. can you help me please. i think you are guding me in wright direction.

Comment: Thank you so much  for your help. after changing the url as per you in get method. it worked like a champ. Thank you so much for your quick help.

Comment: Great if you could accept and upvote the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Above change working greatly. Now before this works as it is just i want to load express server to just retrieve my organization SSO logged in user from request headers and then continue as is flow from angular. can you please guide me with app.js file. i am posting my app js file in next comment

Comment: i have app.js like below but its giving  status code 404 not found.const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const request = require('request');
const app =  express();
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/myapp'));
app.get("/*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.headers); // the posted data
    console.log(req.query.module);
    res.sendStatus(200)
});

Comment: const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log('Running......'));

Comment: Even i have raised a new question with subject Node Express proxy getting Status Code: 404 Not Found instead of 200 success code